# Assets - Css its not loaded

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a login page with a css separate, I put the css in a folder inside app/assets/sessions.
But it's not working. The css it's not loading.

When the user make login in the app, the others files works.
I don't know what I'm do wrong, I organize my files in folders inside assets.

```
app
--assets
---images
---stylesheets
----all
-----...
----sessions
-----user_sessions.css
application-all.css
application-sessions.css
```

application-sessions.css

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree ./sessions/
*/
```

user_sessions.css

```
html, body, div,.... section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
......
```

In my layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application-all", :media => "all" %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application-sessions", :media => "sessions" %>
<% end %>
```

Sorry for my englsih :P

Answer (score 1):

May be you mean:

```
app
--assets
---images
---stylesheets
----all
-----...
----sessions
-----user_sessions.css
----application-all.css
----application-sessions.css
```

**application-all.css** and **application-sessions.css** must be placed in **app/assets/stylesheets** as I see

Comment: Yeap, I made a mistake when typing, in the application is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.

In application.html.erb, I changed this:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application-all", :media => "all" %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application-sessions", :media => "sessions" %>
<% end %>
```

to this:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application-all", :media => "all" %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application-sessions", :media => "all" %>
<% end %>
```